# Strange error while trying to load geometry using JSONLoader()

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="C:/Users/danr/Desktop/ThreeJS/three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>-->
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            
            camera.position.z = 5;
            
            var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
            pointLight.position.x = 2;
            pointLight.position.y = 5;
            pointLight.position.z = 10;
            scene.add(pointLight);
            
            loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            loader.load( "./X738.js", function(geometry) 
            {
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
                mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                mesh.position.y = 0;
                mesh.position.x = 0;
                scene.add(mesh);
            });
            
            function render() {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);


                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is all of my code. I am using an Apache2.2 server and I used python to convert my model from an FBX to Json. Here is the error message I am getting:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer 57 three.js:18058
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , three.js:9764
xhr.onreadystatechange three.js:9764

     xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        
                if ( xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE ) {
        
                    if ( xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 0 ) {
        
                        if ( xhr.responseText ) {
        
                            var json = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText );//*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token*
                            var result = context.parse( json, texturePath );
                            callback( result.geometry, result.materials );
```

Any suggestions with what might be wrong??? I have tried many different solutions but nothing seems to be working and I feel very lost.

Thanks!!!

EDIT: Here is a sample of what the python FBX to JSON converter is giving me back:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "formatVersion" : 3.2,
        "type"      : "scene",
        "generatedBy"   : "convert-to-threejs.py",
        "objects"       : 1,
        "geometries"    : 1,
        "materials"     : 1,
        "textures"      : 1
    },


    "urlBaseType": "relativeToScene",

    "objects" :
    {
        "Tire_Front" : {
            "geometry" : "Geometry_40_Tire_Front",
            "material" : "Material #3319",
            "position" : [ 0, -423.113, 451.225 ],
            "rotation" : [ -1.5708, 0.000987928, 6.04932e-20 ],
            "scale"    : [ 1, 1, 1 ],
            "visible"  : true
        }
    },

    "geometries" :
    {
        "Geometry_40_Tire_Front" : {
            "type"  : "embedded",
            "id" : "Embed_40_Tire_Front"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Did you look at the response that comes back? Is it valid JSON?

Comment: How do i check if it is valid JSON?

Comment: It looks like it is valid JSON when compare it to other JSON examples. I will post what I got back in an edit of the main post.

Comment: Paste it into http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: So I have found out that I am getting valid JSON back. Now I am getting an error saying that json.uvs.length is undefined but I am looking right at it in my json file and the uvs are defined so not sure how or why i am getting this error.

Comment: Have you tried "OBJLoader" instead?

Answer (score 0):

I identified some sources of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" in your .json file. Be careful with the syntax, including the brackets "{" or "[".

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "formatVersion" : 3.2,
        "type"      : "scene",
        "generatedBy"   : "convert-to-threejs.py",
        "objects"       : 1,
        "geometries"    : 1,
        "materials"     : 1,
        "textures"      : 1
    },


    "urlBaseType": "relativeToScene",

    "objects" :
    {
        "Tire_Front" : {
            "geometry" : "Geometry_40_Tire_Front",
            "material" : "Material #3319",
            "position" : [ 0, -423.113, 451.225 ],
            "rotation" : [ -1.5708, 0.000987928, 6.04932e-20 ],
            "scale"    : [ 1, 1, 1 ],
            "visible"  : true
        }
    },

    "geometries" :
    {
        "Geometry_40_Tire_Front" : {
            "type"  : "embedded",
            "id" : "Embed_40_Tire_Front"
        }
    }
```

}

Using "OBJLoader" instead of "JSONLoader" to load objects helps too.